# R - Select Columns based on the values on each respective columns

Tags: r, dplyr

If I have a dataframe with 5 columns (A to E) with 1000 rows, all columns have variety of numbers greater than 0 except 2 columns (D and E) which has only zeros. How do I evaluate each columns so that i select only columns with values? I want to have a new dataframe with columns (A B C). In my actual dataframe, i have a thousand columns. All I know is the dplyr select(dataframe, )

thanks.
J

Comment: When you say "only columns with values", if you mean non-zero columns try `sapply(dataframe, function(x) !all(x == 0))` to use as an index

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove columns which are all 0 or NA with:

```
x <- x[,colSums(x,na.rm = TRUE) > 0]
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option is `Filter`

```
Filter(function(x) any(!is.na(x)&x!=0), df1)
```

Or

```
Filter(function(x) sum(x, na.rm=TRUE), df1)
```

Or as @docendodiscimus mentioned

```
Filter(any, df1)
```

It will give a friendly warning about type conversion.

#### data

```
df1 <- data.frame(Col1= c(NA, rep(0,5)), Col2= c(1:5, NA), Col3=0)
```

Comment: We could golf it down to `Filter(any, df1)` (and ignore the warning)